# XmlPullParser и GridViewAdapter

Tags: android, java

Всем доброго времени суток.
У меня есть XML файл с огромным количеством ссылок на изображения и GridView который их отображает. Когда я запускаю приложение, парсер начинает парсить этот XML файл и сохранять ссылки в БД, а после обращается к адапетру, что бы тот начал обработку ссылок из БД.
Из-за длительной обработки парсера, такой вариант мне не подходит. Можно ли сделать так, что бы адаптер не дожидался окончания парсинга, а начал действовать сразу после попадания первой информации в БД?

код:

```
 dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

 GridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
 GridView.setAdapter(new GrViewAdapter(MainTestGrActivity.this, options,  MySS.load_img));

XmlPullParser xpp;

    try {
          XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
          factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
          xpp = factory.newPullParser();
          URL urls = new URL("http://...");
          InputStream stream = urls.openStream();
          xpp.setInput(stream, null);
          ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
          String img= null;

          while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

              switch (xpp.getEventType()) {

                   case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                 break;
               case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                      if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(img)) {

                    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    img = xpp.getAttributeValue("", "img");
                      cv.put("img", img);;

                      long rowID = db.insert("mytable", null, cv);
                       dbHelper.close();

                 SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                 c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);

                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id")
                      int imgColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("img");

                      do {
                        MySS.get_id.add(c.getInt(idColIndex));
                        MySS.load_img.add(c.getString(imgColIndex));

                      } while (c.moveToNext());
                    } else
                        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 
                    int clearCount = db.delete("mytable", null, null);
                    db.close();
                    c.close();

                }
                        break;
                              case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                             break;
                           default:
                              break;
                }

                            xpp.next();
                }
                          Log.d(LOG_TAG, "END_DOCUMENT");
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Буду очень рад вашим советам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если использовать [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) (то есть адаптер в виде курсора над БД), то все будет работать автоматом и адаптер по мере обновления данных будет подгружать данные.

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Нужно написать Pull To Refresh-адаптер: [Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) или же адаптер/свой грид, который при скроллинге будет подгружать данные.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте конечно можно)) 
Для этого вам нужно сделать так чтобы парсер генерировал события о распаршеной сущности и передавал ее вместе с событием.

И тогда можно зерегестрировать несколько "слушателей" этого события что я надеюсь решит Вашу проблему.
http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java/Listeners